# Renaming a file using renameTo() in Windows 8 fails

Tags: java, windows-8, rename

I am writing a small program to get some order for my music files (using Win8). One of the classes that I'm using renames a file padding the track number with a zero when needed.  The script works to get the name changed but it will not rename the file.  It does not  throw an error it just does not rename the file.

The bit that is not working:

```
    String newTrackkName = item.replace(oldFileName, newFileName);
    File oldFile = new File(oldFileName);

    Boolean renamed = oldFile.renameTo(new File(newFileName));

    System.out.println("\nthe file '" + item + "'" + ((!renamed) ? "\n\tHas NOT been renamed '" : "\n\tHas been renamed '") + newTrackkName + "'");
```

Here is a sample of the println output:

```
the file 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\14 - Livin For You.mp3'
    Has NOT been renamed 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\14 - Livin For You.mp3'

the file 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\2 - Call Me (Come Back Home).mp3'
    Has NOT been renamed 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\02 - Call Me (Come Back Home).mp3'

the file 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\3 - I'm Still In Love With You.mp3'
    Has NOT been renamed 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\03 - I'm Still In Love With You.mp3'

the file 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\4 - Here I Am (Come And Take Me).mp3'
    Has NOT been renamed 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\04 - Here I Am (Come And Take Me).mp3'

the file 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\5 - How Can You Mend A Broken Heart.mp3'
   Has NOT been renamed 'c:\test\Al Green\Compact Command Performances_ 14 Greatest Hits\05 - How Can You Mend A Broken Heart.mp3'
```

At least it is not lying to me about the rename :-).

Any great suggestions, I've tried using the Files.move option and that did not work either.

Comment: Don’t use that ancient API, use NIO. [`Files.move`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) will tell you via exceptions what went wrong.

Comment: What @Holger said. You can read more about it for instance here http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks